# Proving multivariable limit exists where $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} \gt 1$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Given that $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} > 1$, I am attempting to show that 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{|x|^{a}|y|^{b}}{|x|^{c} + |y|^{d}} = 0$$

*My attempt at a solution:*

Let's assume the limit is in fact zero, and prove it with the Squeeze Theorem. 
We have that 
\begin{align*}
\Bigg|\frac{|x|^{a}|y|^{b}}{|x|^{c} + |y|^{d}}\Bigg| &= \frac{|x|^{a}|y|^{b}}{|x|^{c} + |y|^{d}} \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}|x|^{a-\frac{c}{2}}|y|^{b-\frac{d}{2}} && \text{using the fact that } a^{2} + b^{2} > 2ab
\end{align*}

But I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here to apply the inequality given and find a limiting function, if I am even on the right track with the inequality I applied. This isn't homework ( *a practice question I found* ), any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it! I was on the wrong track after all, the key is to turn it into a single variable limit. If there's any issues with this result please do let me know!

Letting $|x| = q^{\frac{1}{c}}$ and $|y| = q^{\frac{1}{d}}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\frac{|x|^{a}|y|^{b}}{|x|^{c} + |y|^{d}} &= \frac{q^\frac{a}{c}q^\frac{b}{d}}{2q} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}q^{\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} -1}
\end{align*}
Then as 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{1}{2} q^{\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} -1} &= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{q\rightarrow0} q^{\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} -1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{q\rightarrow0} q^{k} &&\text{where } k>0 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
by the Squeeze Theorem we have that shown that the limit is in fact $0$.